# Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function with the following properties

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I've been stuck on the following math question:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ have two derivatives with
>   $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) \leq f(x)$ for all $x$. Is $f(x) = 0$ for all
>   $x$?

I've tested several functions, and I believe the answer is true. I have no clue about how to prove this statement though.

For example, if we have a constant function $f(x) = c$, then we must have $c = 0$ due to the $f(0) = 0$ condition. I've also tried polynomial and trignometric functions, and I cannot find a counterexample.

I thought about somehow using the Mean Value Theorem or Rolle's Theorem, but I didn't get anywhere with either of those.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is piece-wise defined as $f(x) = -x^2$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) =0$ for $x\ge 0$ then $f(x)$ satisfies $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) \le f(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: What does it mean for $f$ to have two derivatives? Does that just mean that it's defined piecewisely?

Comment: Also, I don't believe your example works because we have $f'(x) = -2x > -x^2 = f(x)$ at $x = -2$ (or pretty much any negative number).

Comment: Yes you make a good point, I was a little soppy with that example (I thought that $f'(x) \le x$ was what we wanted). The idea should be sound though

Comment: Try $f(x) = -x^3$ for $x<0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \ge 0$. Then $f'(x) = -3x^2 \le -x^3 $ for any negative $x$ (positive $x$ is obviously OK). Two derivatives means twice differentiable, which this function is because $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ are well-defined for all $x$.

Comment: Okay, I understand why that works. Thank you.